# How to design to avoid duplicate Foreign keys

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-key, normalization

I wasn't really sure how to title this question. I have three tables User, Photo and Album. A user has many Photo objects and many Album objects. However, after a User has added a given photo they may choose to put it in a single Album (a Photo does not have to have an album linked to it).

How do I get around the redundant user column (Album.user and Photo.user) when a Photo is associated with an Album to avoid db anomalies?

I can't get rid of the user column on Photo since I wouldn't be able to get to it if it is not linked to / is deleted from an Album. The same goes for Album. I have some experience with normalizing tables but I don't know how to avoid this without using db constraints.

Here's a crude schema image:

[image: db schema]

Answer (score 0):

Make both `user_id` and `album_id` in `photo` nullable, but add a check constraint that makes sure that exactly one of them is set. If you cannot change both attributes in the same statement, you can use a deferred constraint trigger instead of the check constraint.

Comment: Is there any way to 'correctly' normalize this or are db constraints the only way to go? I used this as a basic example but the real problem I have goes through multiple (existing) tables and ends up at the same user. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One reflection is that it may make sense to have an owner of both album and photo. One can possibly imagine that it should be allowed for one user to add other user's photos to their album.

That aside, one idea is to add a supertype - say photo_collection - that can be either an album or a single photo, and let user_id be an attribute.

Another variant is to add a unique constraint in ALBUM:

```
ALTER TABLE album ADD CONSTRAINT ak_album
    UNIQUE (user_id, id);
```

Now you can reference that in PHOTO as (replace the current f.k.):

```
ALTER TABLE photo ADD CONSTRAINT fk_album
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id, album_id)
    REFERENCES album (user_id, id)
```

This will guarantee that a related photo and an album has the same user_id

A third option is always to have a default album for every photo, when the last photo is moved from the default album, the album can be removed. I.e.

```
USER <- ALBUM <- PHOTO
```

Comment: Yeah seems like there isn't really a great way of doing it without the constraint. In my codebase I have this same issue but through multiple existing tables e.g. A<-B<-C->D->A. Because of other design constraints that were made it would be heard to do without using a constraint. Thanks!